# How to troubleshoot this duplicate sources warning in installing newest Google Chrome Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, chrome

I am updating my Google Chrome from 53.x to 56.x, by having google-chrome-stable in `apt` this time. 
I did not do anything to the old Google Chrome version because unsure how to handle it. 
My `/etc/apt/sources.list` in Debian 8.5

```
#

deb http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib

# jessie backports
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free

# Debian 8 "Jessie"
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib

deb http://cran.wu.ac.at/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

In doing `apt-get update`

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I installed the new Google Chrome as root by

```
# http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - 
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
apt-get update 
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB

Comment: What other files do you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? IIRC Chrome installs its own repository itself, that's probably where the duplicate comes from (so your own `google-chrome.list` became redundant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command :

```
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
```

will add a new entry `google-chrome.list` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` . Check it withe `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` then remove the dplicate entry.

If you have a single entry , you should check the `google-chrome.list` file then comment the duplicates URLs under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Comment: Yes, there was a file `google-chome.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` where the duplicate entry existed.